# Why does Python garbage collection with threads not work?

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

When I define a thread as an instance variable, other objects defined are not garbage collected. In this example an array *buffer* is created in each iteration  of the loop that is never garbage collected:

```
import array
import gc
import threading

from pympler import muppy

class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.buffer = array.array('B')
    # Defining a thread keeps array in memory
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda *_: None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(10):
    a = A()
    # del a  # needed
    gc.collect()
    print('Iteration {}:'.format(i))
    obj = muppy.get_objects()
    print('Array objects {}'.format(len(muppy.filter(obj, Type=array.ArrayType))))
    print('Thread objects {}'.format(len(muppy.filter(obj, Type=threading.Thread))))
    print('Running threads {}'.format(len(threading.enumerate())))
```

The output is:

```
Iteration 0:
Array objects 1
Thread objects 2
Running threads 1
Iteration 1:
Array objects 2
Thread objects 3
Running threads 1
...
```

It does not matter if the thread is started + joined or not.
Explicit deletion of the object *buffer* or *self.thread* allows for garbage collection. I cannot understand this behavior and would appreciate some explanation.
In my production code this feature eventually leads to an out-of-memory termination of the python instance.

Answer (score 1):

`obj = muppy.get_objects()` is a list of (and thus a reference to) all objects in memory.

Since garbage collection at the following iteration is performed *before* you overwrite the `obj` variable, the `muppy.get_objects()` operation becomes cumulative - a trap I've fallen into as well when working with `muppy`.

In short:

- first `gc.collect()`: does not affect our variables
- first `obj = ...`: `muppy` sees the thread reference held by `a`
- second `gc.collect()`: the `A` instance created in the first round is no longer referenced by `a` but it is still referenced by `obj` => cannot be garbage collected
- second `obj = ...`: `muppy` sees both the new thread referenced by `a`, and the old one that was referenced by `obj`
- ...

A rule of thumb for working with `muppy`: always make sure to delete references to the list of objects before you call `muppy.get_objects()` again or you may be surprised.

Appending a simple  `del obj` to the end of the loop results in

```
Iteration 0:
Array objects 1
Thread objects 2
Running threads 1
Iteration 1:
Array objects 1
Thread objects 2
Running threads 1
Iteration 2:
Array objects 1
Thread objects 2
Running threads 1
...
```

P.S. This has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it does look like a tool used wrong in this minimal example. One thing I do not understand: if it has nothing to do with threading; why does removing the `self.thread = ` line help?

Comment: If you remove the `self.thread = ` line, you are left with one reference to a thread (not a thread explicitly created by you; I guess it is the thread that is running the script). You are no longer creating new threads, and so the number of thread objects remains constant.

Comment: P.S. Added a step-by-step explanation of what is happening here; hope that clears things up.